# Google Maps auto smoothly move by ellipse

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

How to do this things with Google Maps API v3:

1) smoothly move map.
I try this function:

```
function move() {   
var latLng=map.getCenter();
var lat=latLng.lat();
var lng=latLng.lng();
var myLatlng1 = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng+(0.00009));
map.panTo(myLatlng1);
}
```

and call by timer

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map,'idle', function() {
setTimeout(move,500);
});
```

it work, but very intermittently.

2) how to set movement by circle (ellipse)? like this http://css-tricks.com/examples/Circulate/

Comment: Your code should solve requirement 1. What is set movement by circle?

Comment: Here is a jsfiddle of your code- [**Map movement**](http://jsfiddle.net/r8Uud/) How do you expect something like the demo in this map? I cannot imagine anything as such.

Comment: I see that it moves not smoothly(

Comment: The jerk kind of movement right? But with such a little change in value nothing more can be expected. A little higher value like in this Fiddle looks ok- http://jsfiddle.net/r8Uud/3/

Comment: Use setInterval instead to get a smoother feel. http://jsfiddle.net/r8Uud/5/